# Object method is undefined after retrieved from local storage?

Tags: javascript

I have created a Book object with a prototype method changeStatus which can change the read status of the book. The existing books are displayed, and any new books are added into the local storage. However, whenever I try to retrieve the books from the local storage, i.e. by refreshing the page, the changeStatus method returns this error,

library.html:154 Uncaught TypeError: myLibrary[i].changeStatus is not a function
at HTMLButtonElement.

I have tried changing the method to be declared in the constructor and also tried to convert the function to a string using .toString() instead of JSON.stringify(). But it still doesnt seem to work.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1N4bbPA3XjO8skaC_Ab965UmGd8fefd0b?usp=sharing

```
        let myLibrary = [];
        function Book(title, author, numPages, readStatus) {
            this.title = title;
            this.author = author;
            this.numPages = numPages;
            this.readStatus = readStatus;
        }
        Book.prototype.changeStatus = function(currentStatus) {
            const statuses = ["Not Started", "In Progress", "Completed"];
            let currentIndex = statuses.indexOf(currentStatus);
            this.readStatus = statuses[(currentIndex+1)%3];
        }
        var book1 = new Book("Book title", "Book author", "512", "In Progress");
        var book2 = new Book("Test book title", "Test book author", "256", "Completed");
        myLibrary.push(book1);
        myLibrary.push(book2);
        // setting and getting local storage
        if (!localStorage.getItem("libraryBooks")) {
            populateStorage();
        } 
        else {
            retrieveBooks();
        }
    
        function populateStorage() {
            localStorage.setItem("libraryBooks", JSON.stringify(myLibrary, function(key, value) {
                return (typeof value === "function") ? value.toString() : value;
            }));
            
        }

         
        function retrieveBooks() {
            myLibrary = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("libraryBooks", function(key, value) {
                if(typeof value != 'string') return value;
                return ( value.substring(0,8) == 'function') ? eval('('+value+')') : value;
            }));
            
        }
```

Comment: JSON cannot store functions.

Comment: localStorage cannot store functions either.

Comment: JSON doesn't store prototypes. When you parse JSON you just get plain objects and arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. local storage can only handle json data
2. json doesnt have functions

so for acheive what you want to achieve just parse the json to object before calling that function. here is the pseudo code

```
var book = new Book("Book title", "Book author", "512", "In Progress");
localStorage.book = book;

function parseBook(book){
   return new Book(book.title, book.author, book.numPages, book.readStatus)
}

parseBook(localStorage.book).changeStatus.. // this ll work
```

this is just raw code i havent tested but ll work for sure;)

Comment: oh, so i have to parse the json to an object. thanks